# Data not visible after unsafe removal

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, windows-10, external-hard-drive, file-transfer

I have a little problem.

I had a laptop with Ubuntu on it. I copied approximately 100gb of data to a external harddisk. Then when the copying was finished I removed the harddisk without fist unmounting it.

Then I installed windows 10 on the laptop and when I wanted to get my files back I could't see them anymore with *windows explorer*. Now I see a few folders and files but not everything.

How can I retrieve my data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: What format was the external disk? eg.FAT32, NTFS ext2 ext3? If it was one of the linux type formats, windows can't read it - You might want to try a program called DiskInternals Linux reader from here - http://www.diskinternals.com/download/

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a duplicate question just yet as we don't know what the disk format is :)

Comment: Disk format is NTFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using recuva to recover the files
or try loading linux from a usb and see if it can read it.

Comment: I tried both, without succes. It took recuva 2 hours to scan the disk and it found nothing.

Comment: Ok after some trial and error I recovered the files with Recuva. I added my own answer for people who want to know how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

**How to recover files after unsafe device removal**

If you can't acces/view your files after unsafe device removal this wil probably help. When you copy files to a NTFS file system and then unplug the device without safe removal it can be that the OS did not finish your copy. The files are copied to the device but the header information is not written. When you use a file explorer you can't find your files at the location you copied them to.

**Solution**

[Download Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) and install this program. Then follow these steps:

[image]

When you first startup the program it wil show you a wizard. Just click next.

[image]

Select *all files* and click next.

[image]

Now select the device which you want to recover. *Do not select a specific location on the device just select the device*. And click next.

**Good**

[image]

**Bad**

[image]

[image]

Now comes the most important part. Check *deep scan* and click start.

[image]

Now wait for a really long time. (I waited 2.5 hours)

[image]

After this you should see an immense lange list of found files.

[image]

Now sort this list on the *path* column.

[image]

And then search for the files that have unknown file path. It will look like `C:\?\`.

[image]

Now you have to check all the files which you want to recover. If there are a lot you can just fast select them by right clicking on one of the files and then select the *highlight folder* option. See above image. After you did this use the space bar on your keyboard to select everything at once.

[image]

When you have selected all of the files you want to recover use the recover button and choose a location to write the files to. *Do not use the device your're recovering from.*

Now you have recovered your files. I hope this tutorial helped you out.

Comment: Nice tutorial, however I don't think it' going to help as the user didn't allow the system to sync before removing the device. Depending on the file system they used, the files may simply never have been written to the disk prior to removal.